# Where is misunderstanding dA = dx * dy?

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus

Using infinitesimals from $ A(x, y) = x * y $ I have $ dA = A_x * dx + A_y * dy $ solving it for $ dA $, I have $ dA = y * dx + x * dy $ which is a mistake. Where in my thinking way is that mistake? I have tried with $ A(x, y) = const $ but it is also wrong.

Comment: Why is that a "mistake"?

Comment: Why do you start with $A(x,y) = x * y$?

Comment: @Lord Shark the Unknown because when I go with calculations I have finally that $ y/dy + x/dx = 1 $ have to be true but it isn't.

Comment: @md2perpe I am starting from that, because it is formula for area of the square. I have assumed that squares are proper to use in integration. When you intagrate $ \iint dx dy = xy $. Is something wrong with this?

Comment: @Lord Shark the Unknown plus it is well known that $ dA = dx * dy $ from $ \lim_{\Delta \to 0} \Delta x * \Delta y = dx * dy = dA $ isn't it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a double integral $\iint_D f(x,y) \, dA = \iint_D f(x,y) \, dxdy$, the symbol $dA$ is just shorthand for the area element $dxdy$, “a little piece of area”.

That's something **completely different** from the differential $dA=y\,dx+x\,dy$ of the function $A(x,y)=xy$!

So there's no contradiction, just the same symbol used for two different things.

Comment: I had similar thoughts, but meaning of $ dx $ and $ dy $ looks the same for me, is it right? So I have explained it to me that $ dA_{\bullet} = dx * dy $ is an area and $ dA_{\circ} = 2 * dx * dy $ is a dynamic of that area in $ dt $ which is the smallest time and you are capturing it two times, because there is nothing between. Is that intuition proper?

Comment: @koralgooll: That doesn't make any sense whatsover to me!

Comment: If you go into more advanced math, you might learn about “differential forms”, and that from the 1-forms $dx$ and $dy$, you can make the 2-form $dx \wedge dy$, but that's still something completely different from $dA = d(xy) = y \, dx + x \, dy$ which is still a 1-form. Don't know if that's of any help to you at this stage, however... Anyway, if you start mixing “time” $t$ into this picture, you are surely going to be confused, I think!

Comment: Thank you very much! I will go and read about differential forms. It sounds very interesting. :)

Comment: I've always grumbled about how differentials are taught in calculus.  Maybe moreso with how they're used.  It seems unnecessarily confusing, and this question is another example.